# create an empty object in JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

i have create json from an array but how we can make an empty json

```
$jsonrows['paymentmethods']['CC']=array()
json_encode($jsonrows['paymentmethods']['CC']=array())
```

currently output is like this

```
"CC":[]
```

what i need is

```
"CC":{}
```

please help me with this

Comment: `$test = json_encode($jsonrows['paymentmethods']['CC']=array());`

Comment: $jsonrows['paymentmethods']['CC']=json_encode(array())

Comment: try `json_encode($jsonrows['paymentmethods']['CC']=new stdClass);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
  $cc['CC'] = new stdClass ;
  echo json_encode($jsonrows['paymentmethods']=$cc);
```

Output is

```
{"CC":{}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a class instead of an array:

```
var_dump(json_encode(new StdClass()));
```

Answer (score 1):

For code readability, I use `$emptyObject = (object)[];`

In the context of your example:

`$jsonrows['paymentmethods']['CC']=array();
 echo json_encode($jsonrows['paymentmethods']);`

yields the undesired: `{"CC":[]}`

`$jsonrows['paymentmethods']['CC']=(object)array();
echo json_encode($jsonrows['paymentmethods']);`

gives what you want: `{"CC":{}}`